# gradient of max function

Tags: derivatives

If I have a function $f=\max \{0, y-t\}$, and I want to find the gradient of with respect to $[y \ \ t]$, would that simply be

$$
\nabla f = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\max\{0,0\} \\
\max\{1,-1\}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 7):

No. You would need to explicitly write out the function and derivative:$$f(y,t)=\begin{cases}0, y\le t\\y-t,y\gt t\end{cases}$$
Then $$\partial_t f=\begin{cases}0, y\le t\\-1,y\gt t\end{cases}$$
and $$\partial_y f=\begin{cases}0, y\le t\\1,y\gt t\end{cases}$$
So now you can write $$\nabla f=\begin{bmatrix}\partial_y f\\\partial_t f \end{bmatrix}=\begin{cases}\begin{bmatrix}0\\0 \end{bmatrix}, y\le t\\\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}, y\gt t\end{cases}$$